# Tab completion for .bat files in Git-for-Windows Bash

Tags: batch-file, tab-completion, git-bash

Git for Windows installs "Git Bash," a bash shell that works in Windows, which is very nice. It's based on MinTTY, I believe.

As well as bash shell scripts, it can also execute Windows batch (`.bat`) files, e.g.

```
$ ./some-batch-file.bat
```

executes without any issue.

But tab-completion doesn't work on these batch files. Typing <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> has no effect.

Is there some way to enable tab-completion for `.bat` files in Git bash?

Answer (score 3):

I've manged to get this working, I found a post about getting .sh files to work in Git Bash using this on the first line of the file:

> #!/bin/sh

This also works when placed on the first line of .bat files. You still have to start with the ./ before the file name.

Comment: This isn’t going to work for me (looking to use batch files from a repo, neither want to commit such changes nor maintain my own set of changes across pulls), but good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I can at least provide a workaround for those interested. I start with typing `vi` or `ls` followed by `./` and from there tab completion works then I just move the cursor to the start of the line with <kbd>Home</kbd> and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> three times.

I wish I could just add `.bat` to an environment variable that holds a list for tab completion but I'm not sure there is one?